# .BMP file cannot be opened

Tags: c, bmp

I'm trying to create a bmp file. The file is created and I can open it but it says, that the file is corrupt and cannot be opened propperly. Here is how i save the file:

```
void createBMP(char* pixelData, long xRes, long yRes){
BITMAPFILEHEADER fheader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER iheader;
COLORREF_RGB rgb;

//file header werte setzen
fheader.bfType = 0x4D42;
fheader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
fheader.bfReserved1 =0;
fheader.bfReserved2=0;
fheader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

//info header werte setzen
iheader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
iheader.biWidth = xRes;
iheader.biHeight = yRes;
iheader.biPlanes = 1;
//farbtiefe
iheader.biBitCount = 24;
iheader.biCompression = 0;
iheader.biSizeImage = 0;
iheader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
iheader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
//anzahl der eintraege der farbtabelle
iheader.biClrUsed = 0;
iheader.biClrImportant = 0;

//rgbfarbwerte setzen
rgb.cRed = 0;
rgb.cGreen = 0;
rgb.cBlue = 0;

printf("\nwriting Image-File");

FILE *f;


f = fopen("testASP.bmp", "wb");


if(f == NULL){
    freopen("testASP.bmp", "wb", f);
   // printf("Fehler beim Laden des Files");
   // return;
}

printf("\nPath: %S\n");

fwrite(&fheader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,f);
fwrite(&iheader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,f);

int i,j;

for(i=0;i<xRes; i++){
    for(j=0;j<yRes;j++){
        fwrite(&rgb, sizeof(COLORREF_RGB),1,f);
    }
}

fclose(f);


printf("Bild wurde gespeichert\n");
```

I'm notsure what I am doing wrong double checked the values but cannot seem to find my mistake. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

On Request Adding structs:

```
typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef long int LONG;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;


typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD    bfType;
    DWORD   bfSize;
    WORD    bfReserved1;
    WORD    bfReserved2;
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
    DWORD   biSize;
    LONG    biWidth;
    LONG    biHeight;
    WORD    biPlanes;
    WORD    biBitCount;
    DWORD   biCompression;
    DWORD   biSizeImage;
    LONG    biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG    biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD   biClrUsed;
    DWORD   biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

typedef struct COLORREF_RGB
{
    BYTE cRed;
    BYTE cGreen;
    BYTE cBlue;
}COLORREF_RGB;
```

Comment: What's the idea behind this: `if(f == NULL){
    freopen("testASP.bmp", "wb", f); ...` to me it does not make sense.

Comment: What kind of library do You use?

Comment: so basically it tried it before but it didn't seem to create a file this way it created a file for me. Basically im checking if such a file already exists if not i am creating one. Is there a smarter way to do so? I'm not good in c code

Comment: no library created all typdefstructs by myself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are all those structs packed? Dare to show there definitions?

Comment: Have you remembered to take account of the image *stride*? The pixel array row length must be a multiple of 4 bytes. So if the image is 10 pixels wide x 24 bits, that is 30 bytes plus 2 padding bytes are required to make the row length up to 32.

Comment: Wait, you're writing C structs straight to disk and you're expecting that to just work?

Comment: I am not yet using the array to create my image just wanted a simple image of 1 pixel before i use the full array

Comment: A 1-pixel image still will require 4 bytes of image data. Otherwise the image viewer app will think the file is too short.

Comment: @melpomene what do you mean by that? In my opinion I define the structs in my file create instances of the struct, and write them into my file.

Comment: Also this `printf("\nPath: %S\n");` provokes undefined behaviour. It is missing its argument.

Comment: Are you compiling on 32 or 64 bits?  32-bit long = 32-bits, 64-bit long = 64 bits.  What is the size of the DWORD?

Comment: I am on 64 bit, isnt dword an unsigned long since i say: typedef unsigned long DWORD;

Comment: Also you want to take care of byte order.

Comment: In the original .bmp definition, the size of DWORD is 32 bits.  Try changing it to unsigned int.

Comment: You want to double check your types (typically their widths) as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: okay my infoheader is 40 byte and my fileheader is 16 so there is something wrong, checking on that

Comment: okay got it to run using a different approach. Thanks for your help

Comment: Code is `for(i=0;i<xRes; i++){ for(j=0;j<yRes;j++){`.  I'd expect `for(j=yRes;j-- > 0;){ for(i=0;i<xRes; i++){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure creates a black BMP file:

```
// WIDTHBYTES takes # of bits in a scanline and rounds up to nearest word.
#define WIDTHBYTES(bits)    (((bits) + 31) / 32 * 4)

int makeBMPfile(int xRes, int yRes)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fheader = {0};
    BITMAPINFOHEADER iheader = {0};
    COLORREF_RGB rgb = {0,0,0};
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j, padbytes;

    iheader.biSize      = sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    iheader.biWidth     = xRes;
    iheader.biHeight    = yRes;
    iheader.biPlanes    = 1;
    iheader.biBitCount = 24;
    iheader.biSizeImage= WIDTHBYTES(xRes*24) * yRes;
    padbytes= WIDTHBYTES(xRes*24) - (xRes*24/8);

    fheader.bfType = 0x4D42;
    fheader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 0/*no palette for 24 bits color*/;
    fheader.bfSize = fheader.bfOffBits + iheader.biSizeImage;

    if ((fp = fopen("testASP.bmp", "wb"))==NULL) return(0);

    fwrite(&fheader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,fp);
    fwrite(&iheader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,fp);

    for(i=0;i<yRes; i++){
        for(j=0;j<xRes;j++){
            fwrite(&rgb, sizeof(COLORREF_RGB),1,fp);
        }
        if (padbytes) fwrite(&rgb, padbytes,1,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: so:   fheader.bfSize =  sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+4*xRes*yRes; and my  fheader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER); already dleted the printf(...) didnt think that thats such a huge deal if i leave it in

Comment: I replaced my solution with the full procedure to create a black BMP file.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please click on the vote button on the left of my solution to accept it. I hope you also see where you went wrong.