# bitmap for loop issue

Tags: c, image-processing

Now I'm trying to implement with for loop statement to make bitmap as below,

[image: Desired result]

But I've got the output image as below,

[image: Current result]

I just used as below for loop statement.

```
    for ( int y = 0; y < Picture_y_; y++) 
        for ( int x = 0; x < Picture_x_; x++)
        {


            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 0)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//B
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 1)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//G
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 2)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//R
}
```

I don't know why does it have abnormal image what I've got.

this is entire code.

```
  #include <windows.h>
#include "CyApi.h"


#define WIDTHBYTES(w, bitcount) ((((w)*(bitcount)+31)& ~31) >> 3)  
#define WIDTHBYTES_(bits) (((bits)+31)/32*4)


int RAW2DIB(HWND);

unsigned char *_Orgin_Pixel_;
unsigned char *_Copy_Pixel_;
unsigned int W_Image =  2560;
unsigned int H_Image =  1920;
unsigned int widthbytes = WIDTHBYTES(W_Image, 24);
unsigned int S_Image = widthbytes * H_Image;
BITMAPINFO *BmInfo;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
LPWSTR lpszClass = L"First";

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
    , LPWSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Message;
    WNDCLASS WndClass;

    WndClass.cbClsExtra=0;
    WndClass.cbWndExtra=0;
    WndClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    WndClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    WndClass.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClass.hInstance=hInstance;
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)WndProc;
    WndClass.lpszClassName=lpszClass;
    WndClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    WndClass.style=CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClass(&WndClass);

    hWnd = CreateWindow(lpszClass, lpszClass, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, (HMENU)NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }

    return Message.wParam;
}



int RAW2DIB(HWND hWnd)
{
    unsigned int Picture_x_, Picture_y_, Bitdepth;

    LONG len;
    BmInfo = (BITMAPINFO*)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFO) 
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biSize =  sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = W_Image;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = H_Image;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount =  24;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression =  BI_RGB;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (((W_Image * 24 + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * H_Image;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    BmInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;

    _Copy_Pixel_ = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(BYTE)*(S_Image), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 

    Picture_x_ = W_Image;
    Picture_y_ = H_Image;

    len = WIDTHBYTES_(2560 * 24) * 1920;


    _Orgin_Pixel_ = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(BYTE)*(W_Image* H_Image), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 

    for (int y = 0; y < H_Image; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < W_Image; x++)
            _Orgin_Pixel_[y * H_Image + x] = x%255;

    for ( int y = 0; y < Picture_y_; y++) 
        for ( int x = 0; x < Picture_x_; x++)
        {
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 0)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//B
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 1)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//G
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_y_ * 3) + x * 3 + 2)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//R

        }
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE); 
    return 0;
}

...
case WM_PAINT
SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, W_Image, H_Image, 0, 0, 0, H_Image, _Copy_Pixel_, BmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Comment: Your Picture_x,y variables do not have any value.

Comment: @Rad-Lexus, good catch!

Comment: `unsigned int widthbytes = WIDTHBYTES(W_Image, 24);` and `unsigned int S_Image = widthbytes * H_Image;` cannot compile as on the global level you cannot initialize a variable with another variable. Are warnings turned on?

Comment: For `S_Image` in your call to `VirtualAlloc` you can use `BmInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage`,

Comment: 1) Is this supposed to be C or C++? Remove the tag of the unrelated language. 2) Names starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation. You must not use them in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loops you do not take the scanline size into account. A bitmap image consists of scanlines and scanlines consist of pixels and pixels consists of bits (bytes). Scanlines are alligned on the nearest next word boundary.

So `len` is not equal to `2560 * 1920` and neitrher can a pixel be addressed as Copy_Pixel[y * 1920 + x]`.

`len` should be `WIDTHBYTES_(2560*BmInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount) * 1920`

addressing a pixel should be:

```
Copy_Pixel[WIDTHBYTES_(x*BmInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount) + y]
```

---

Edit:

Your loop really should be:

```
    int scanlinesize= WIDTHBYTES_(Picture_x_*24);

    for ( int y = 0; y < Picture_y_; y++) 
        for ( int x = 0; x < Picture_x_; x++)
        {
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*scanlinesize) + x * 3 + 0)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//B
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*scanlinesize) + x * 3 + 1)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//G
            _Copy_Pixel_[((y*scanlinesize) + x * 3 + 2)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*Picture_y_ + x];//R

        }
```

Comment: @Rad-Lexus, wrong on a few acounts: Indeed `biBitCount` as the name says is in bits and I use it as bits. Check the macro! He allocates too little memory, he does not use the `biSizeImage` he calculated and he indexes his image _without_ taking scanlin size into acount.

Comment: @RadLexus Would you like to help me a little bit more? I can't resolve this problem with Paul answer.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399028/bmp-file-cannot-be-opened/41399453#41399453 for a complete and tested solution, then from there check/adapt for your purpose.

Comment: @Rad Lexus, you are right. I meant `Copy_Pixel`. Adapted my solution.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks you are the best! it works very well

Comment: Multiplying by picture_y is obviously wrong. You need picture_x or some derivative of it like padding to multiples of 8 bytes. The bug is also in Orgin_PIxel.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Would you let me know exactly what do you mean with code?

Answer (score 0):

here's rough skeleton.

```
unsigned char *_Orgin_Pixel_;
unsigned char *_Copy_Pixel_;
unsigned int W_Image =  2560;
unsigned int H_Image =  1920;
```

The buffers are unsigned chars, width is 2560, height is 1920

This line tells us that the width of the image, in bytes is a complex function of W_Image. It gets padded out to a whole number of 32 bit words. This is the key.

```
 BmInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (((W_Image * 24 + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * H_Image;
int scanlinesize= (((W_Image * 24 + 31) & ~31) >> 3)
```

Scanline width of the original image is

```
 Picture_x = (W_Image * 8 + 31 & ~31) >> 3;
```

I would guess. Check in the documentation.

```
for ( int y = 0; y < Picture_y_; y++) 
    for ( int x = 0; x < Picture_x_; x++)
    {
        _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_x) + x * 3 + 0)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*scanlinesize + x];//B
        _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_x) + x * 3 + 1)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*scalinesize + x];//G
        _Copy_Pixel_[((y*Picture_x) + x * 3 + 2)] = _Orgin_Pixel_[y*scanlinesize + x];//R

    }
```

To debug it, first set everything in the destination to red. Does that work, do you get a fully red image? Then set to a colour gradient going from red to black. Does that work? Once you got both those steps, you're pretty confident you're accessing the buffer correctly. Now any further problems must be in the source.